# How to limit 4 downloads at once in Transmission on AsusWrt

Tags: dd-wrt

i want to download only 4 torrent at once. how to do this with my transmission sitting on asus  rt-n16.
i just want to know which variable should be changed to achieve this.

below is my current settings.

```
  {
     "blocklist-enabled": 1,
     "download-dir": "\/mnt\/data\/torrents",
     "download-limit": 100,
     "download-limit-enabled": 1,
     "encryption": 2,
     "max-peers-global": 35,
     "peer-port": 25000,
     "pex-enabled": 1,
     "port-forwarding-enabled": 1,
     "rpc-authentication-required": 0,
     "rpc-password": "",
     "rpc-port": 9091,
     "rpc-username": "",
     "rpc-whitelist": "192.168.1.*",
     "upload-limit": 200,
     "upload-limit-enabled": 1
     }
```

Comment: `download-queue-size` and `download-queue-enabled`, see https://trac.transmissionbt.com/wiki/EditConfigFiles

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to change any variable.

Just go to your transmission menu.
 
Select Edit - Preferences, 
Select "Downloading" tab 
And set "4" value for "Maximum Active Downloads" under 
 
"Download Queue"heading[1]